# Block not rendering

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom-block

In my backend controller I use the following code to render a custom block.

```
    $this->_title($this->__('Inventar'));
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('psp_inventorymanager');
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('psp_inventorymanager/adminhtml_importstatus'));
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->renderLayout();
```

But the _addContent line does not work. It works on a local magento install but not on the main site.
This is the content of the block's _toHtml():

```
  public function _toHtml()
  {
      $html = parent::_toHtml();
      $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');

  echo '<style>
    .list-with-heading h3{
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    .list-success {
      background: green;
    }
    .list-fail {
      background: red;
    }
    .list-oldqty {
      background: yellow;
    }
    .list-with-heading {
      background: #00BFFF;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .auto {
      max-height: 150px;
      overflow: auto;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>';

  echo '<div class="list-with-heading"><h3>Successful imports: </h3><ul class="list-success auto">';
  foreach ($session->getInventoryImportSuccess() as $key => $value) {
    echo '<li>'. $key .'</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul></div>';
  echo '<div class="list-with-heading"><h3>Failed imports [SKU not found]: </h3><ul class="list-fail auto">';
  foreach ($session->getInventoryImportFail() as $key => $value) {
    echo '<li>'. $key .'</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul></div>';
  echo '<div class="list-with-heading"><h3>Failed imports [QTY not changed]: </h3><ul class="list-oldqty auto">';
  foreach ($session->getInventoryImportOldQty() as $key => $value) {
    echo '<li>'. $key .'</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul></div>';
  $html .= "teeeeeeeeeeeeest";
  return $html;
  }
```

Edit:
I have looked at the system.log and createBlock fails and returns false instead of the block.

Answer (score 0):

I feel silly now. I traced createBlock and saw that I had a typo in my block's naming.
I had to change

```
->createBlock('psp_inventorymanager/adminhtml_importstatus')
```

to this

```
->createBlock('psp_inventorymanager/adminhtml_importStatus')
```